# trying to perform a batch transaction for finally obtaining the smart account address

Tags: solidity, zksync, zkevm

well i was trying to batch three deploy transactions into one, by creating another smart contract for it.
note: these  contracts are deployed for creating smart account wallet (aa) and for calling the deployAccount fn we require to deploy the guardianstorage and socialrecoverymodule, and if you see the create function - it is the function that is used in zksync era network to deploy smart contracts.
can anyone check if this the right approach..

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IContractDeployer{
    function create(bytes32 _salt, bytes32 _bytecodehash, bytes calldata _input) external payable returns(address newAddress);
}

interface IAAFactory{
    function deployAccount(bytes32 salt, address[] calldata owners, uint32 threshold) external returns (address accountAddress);
}

contract BatchDeployer{
    IContractDeployer deployer;
    IAAFactory aaFactory;
    constructor(address depAddress,address aaAddress){
        deployer = IContractDeployer(depAddress);
        aaFactory = IAAFactory(aaAddress);
    }
    bytes32 guardianStorageBHash = 0x0100018dff71995123c2038837d1d2514a572c8101e07144590c6d73570aed8b;
    bytes32 socialRecoveryBHash = 0x01000a211886d67c075548275a211c6c17133b18967a86d828327ee59832e8a0;
    bytes32 salt = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    bytes guardianInput = bytes("");

    function deployAll(address[] memory owners) external returns (address smartAccountAddress){
        address guardianAddress = deployer.create(salt, guardianStorageBHash, guardianInput);
        bytes memory socialRecoveryInput = abi.encodePacked(guardianAddress, "0");
        address socialRecoveryAddress = deployer.create(salt, socialRecoveryBHash,socialRecoveryInput);
        address deployAccounts = aaFactory.deployAccount(salt,owners,2) ;
        return deployAccounts;
    }

}
```